# What are the possible numbers of meth ingredients in Rats - Day 1?

Tags: payday-2

I would like to cook as many meth as possible in [Rats - Day 1](http://payday.wikia.com/wiki/Rats#Objectives). I'm wondering what are the possible numbers of meth ingredients / chemicals (or how are their numbers randomized), so I and my team will know when to stop looking for more ingredients. If it matters, I usually play on the Overkill difficulty.

Also, do the ingredients always spawn in sets of three? e.g. If my team has a total of two different ingredients, then is it guaranteed that the third ingredient is still out there?

Comment: Related: [How do I cook meth?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/130335/4797)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enough materials spawn to create seven bags of meth - these will spawn in the following locations:

- The shed around the front of the property
- The shed around the back of the property
- The bathroom downstairs in the property
- The basement underneath the property, accessible from outside
- The pickup truck around the back of the property

The randomisation on the level will only affect where the ingredients are placed but the bulk of the ingredients usually spawn in the basement, and the order that you need to use the ingredients.

Comment: WHAT? There are two sheds?! It's amazing I've never noticed this hahaha.