# Where are the instructions for making Meth in The Bomb: Dockyard

Tags: achievements, payday-2

In the new The Bomb dlc for Pay Day 2 there is an achievement for finding the meth lab in The Bomb: Dockyard.

[image]

I found the lab in a container on the ship, but couldn't find the instructions for which order to add ingredients.  Is there an instruction poster somewhere, like in Hotline Miami?

Comment: It's not a duplicate.  http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/130335/how-do-i-cook-meth is for the level Rats, I'm referring to the level The Bomb: Dockyard.  The mechanics are different.  In Rats, Bain (the narrator) provides audible instructions.  He does not do this in The Bomb: Dockyard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My team and I just found the crate and cooked a batch, for us the order was the same as in the Hotline: Miami heist: Mu, CS, HCL. YMMV, as we basically took a guess since that order was used previously. Could have been dumb luck, but that would make it quite a coincidence.