# Where do I find meth ingredients in the Bomb: Dockyard heist?

Tags: achievements, payday-2

In the new The Bomb DLC for Payday 2 there is an achievement for finding the meth lab in the Bomb: Dockyard.

[image]

I found the lab in a container on the ship, but where is it possible for the meth ingredients to spawn and how many sets can there be?  Is the number tied to difficulty level?

I have found some in open boxes (same as the open boxes in the Hotline Miami meth room) spread randomly around the level.  I expected to find some in crates, but haven't found any there yet.  Can they spawn there?  Can they spawn elsewhere?

Comment: Don't ask the same question twice. Delete one of them.

Comment: I assume you are referring to http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/202748/where-are-the-instructions-for-making-meth-in-the-bomb-dockyard.  I think these are different enough to warrant two questions as they'll have different answers.  This question asks `Where are the ingredients` the other asks `how to successfully use the ingredients`

Comment: @PhilipPittle question and my own are two separate questions. His asks "where are the ingredients (H, Cl, Mu) for the meth lab in the dockyard", mines asks "where is the meth lab"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ingredients will spawn in random boxes throughout the level, and unfortunately it is completely random when and where they will spawn. It also seems that they won't always spawn (or, at least, that seems to be the consensus so far). There are quite a number of spawn locations to check, and the list seems to be growing, but they are in cardboard boxes. Here's a map of known locations at the moment.

[image: Map of possible spawn locations for the Breaking Dead achievement in Payday 2]

You can also check out [this Reddit thread](http://www.reddit.com/r/paydaytheheist/comments/2tflu6/breaking_dead_achievement_tipssee_comments_find/) which has some more information and videos and screenshots showing some of the locations. Here's a screenshot from that thread of what you're looking for:

[image: Screenshot of one of the spawn locations showing a cardboard box which will contain the item needed to get the achievement.]

Comment: Can you confirm if this always spawns this way? Considering the fact that the meth lab spawns randomly and can sometimes not spawn at all, are the meth ingredient spawns set or determined by RNG?

Comment: @memescientist - I haven't confirmed this, but I think the diagram indicates **possible** spawn locations, not guaranteed spawn locations.  So 0-3 sets of ingredients will spawn in these locations.

Comment: I just ran the heist, did not see any boxes with ingredients at any of the locations indicated on the map.

Comment: Updated info. Basically, it's RNG